# How to align dots and roman numbers in a classicthesis toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I have an issue with a section of my table of contents when using `classicthesis` document class. In this section, I use roman numbers (I, II, III, and so on). Now, some of the dots are under the numbers (XXVIII) as it appears on the picture below. How could I fix it ?

[image]

This is my mwe (please, don't ask me why I use xelatex and... inputenc : this is the way my Mac does function. The other way failed ALL.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\XeTeXinputencoding iso-8859-1
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
...
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\frontmatter
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

...
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
\setcounter{section}{}

\part*{Annexes}

\chapter{Entretiens}

\section{Premier entretien}
\begin{linenumbers}
...
\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `\tableofcontents` to produce it?

Comment: Yes I do. I use that command :   \usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}

Comment: What about providing a MWE that would help us help you?

Comment: I've just edited my question  and provided a mwe.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Comment: @Thruston. OK. I've just removed some useless lines.

Comment: ... but it still does not compile, and even if it did, I can't see anything that would actually produce a table of contents that shows your problem.

Comment: You can't use the 'inputenc' package with xelatex.  Not all of us have Minion Pro installed.  Don't leave "..." in the preamble.  Remove the stray "\end{lineno} at the end.

Comment: @Thruston : "..." is here to indicate that I removed some useless lines or some text. (using inputenc with xelatex is off this topic). If you multiply the \section until 6, you'll have : XXVIII as a roman number of the last page of my document. Here is the issue.

Comment: You could `\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}` and multiple compile runs to get a different result. But to be completely honest, the `Roman`s might have been breat soldiers, but there is a good treadon whhy they sucked at math.

Comment: Make sure your files are encoded in utf8 and load the package fontspec!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OP example would not compile, this answer may or may not solve the problem!

Here's a minimal example that, I think, shows the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nochapters,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection A}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{88}
\subsection{Subsection B}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The dotted "leaders" in the ToC overlap the long page number.

[image]

This can be fixed by forcing a wider space for the page number, as follows.
Adding this:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@pnumwidth}{16mm}
\makeatother
```

just before the `\begin{document}` line, produces:

[image]

Now the numerals do not over print the leaders, but the results don't look very good.  Obviously you could try using a slightly smaller width than 16mm, which might look better if most of the page numerals in the toc are narrow, but possibly not.

At this point I would be tempted just to avoid using roman page numbers with `classicthesis` altogether, but as a last effort you could change the macro that actually produces the dotted lines.  The trouble with this is that in such a complex package there may be unexpected side effects.  Nonetheless the change is not too hard, and it produces the following which may be more what it wanted.

[image]

Here is the complete example with the suggested re-definition of `cftsubsecfillnum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nochapters,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfillnum[1]{{\cftsubsecleader\ }\nobreak 
    \hbox{\cftsubsecpagefont #1}\cftsubsecafterpnum \par }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection A}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{88}
\subsection{Subsection B}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that solution doesn't suit my needs. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: @domi edited with another idea